# Transfer Focus From JTable to Other Components

Tags: java, swing, jtable, focus

How might I setup the tab traversal so that it proceeds linearly through all the components of a frame, including cells in a JTable? For example:

[image: A container with a table between two text fields]

If I pressed TAB, it would go from "Focus Start" --> 1 --> 2 --> ... --> 6 --> "Focus End" and if I pressed SHIFT+TAB it would go in that same order but reversed?

Currently, when the focus hits the JTable, it loops the focus between 1 and 6 until CTRL+TAB is pressed.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class TableExample extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField txtFocusStart;
private JTable table;
private JTextField txtFocusMe;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                TableExample frame = new TableExample();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public TableExample() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 130);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    setContentPane(contentPane);

    txtFocusStart = new JTextField();
    txtFocusStart.setText("Focus Start");
    txtFocusStart.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    contentPane.add(txtFocusStart, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    txtFocusStart.setColumns(10);

    table = new JTable();
    table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
        new Object[][] {
            {"1", "2", "3"},
            {"4", "5", "6"},
        },
        new String[] {
            "New column", "New column", "New column"
        }
    ));
    contentPane.add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    txtFocusMe = new JTextField();
    txtFocusMe.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    txtFocusMe.setText("Focus End");
    contentPane.add(txtFocusMe, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    txtFocusMe.setColumns(10);
}

}
```

Comment: Check out the official focus [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html). Is the info there not enough to help you? How are you trying to implement it in your program?

Comment: You could bind a new key action to the [Tab] for the table that moves focus through the cells to the last cell, at which time it would transfer focus to the next component via the `KeyboardFocusManager`

Comment: Alternatively, consider a `GridBagLayout` having eight fields added in the desired order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like to try to reuse existing Actions to provide additional functionality.

Take a look at [Table Tabbing](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/04/table-tabbing/) which gives an example how to reuse the existing Tab Action to have the Tab key only focus on cells that are editable.

In your case you would need to create a custom class to do the tabbing. Your code would be much simpler. The code for forward tabbing would be something like:

```
if (last cell)
    KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().focusNextComponent();
else
    invokeOriginalAction( e );
```

You would also need to create a separate action for backward tabbing.